# Cannot open source file "All the cpp header files" and global scope has no "some file name" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting so many errors in visual studio 2019. I installed it with the unity game engine(works flawlessly for unity), but I wanted to use it for other small works using c++.
[image: Error Image 1]
[image: Error Image 2]

I have downloaded Desktop development with c++
[image: Packages installed]

Comment: Please post your code and error messages into the question _as text_.

Comment: What kind of project did you create? Can you try to create a empty project for c++? It seems like some project settings are wrong or the installation had a unnoticable failure

Comment: @churill the reason I posted it as an image is because there are a lot of errors (as explained in the question). also, it is a simple hello world program. I just wanted to check if the programs are being compiled before I start something big.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX The image I posted is an empty project. I created a console application empty project with a simple hello world program.

Comment: Can you set the compiler output to verbose and post the relevant error messages from the console here, not the errors displayed in the IDE. So we can see at which step it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for helping me with the question.

The issue was windows 10 SDK not being installed properly. I installed it again and the errors were gone.

I am really sorry for not trying this thing before posting a question here. I will keep this in mind before posting something next time.